# Using Rowspan on table, Last row behaviour across browsers

Tags: html, html-table

So I have a table, like the below

```
<table>
 <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="4">
            <img src="ImageofProduct.jpg" />
        </td>
        <td>ProductName</td>
        <td>Hat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height:1%">
        <td>Description</td>
        <td>Descriptions here</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height:1%">
        <td>Description</td>
        <td>Descriptions here</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><button /></td>
    </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Now you can see the first cell has a img which is going to span every row of the table. Sometimes this image will be taller then the content on the right sometimes it won't be..

Now I have applyed height:1% on each row so that instead of firefox trying to evenly spread the height of each row to match the height of the image. They will be as small as possible apart from the last one which will span the rest of the height left over.

In Firefox this works perfectly but in chrome it doesn't feel the need to make the other all the rows total height match that of the first cell that spans every row.

Is their a way to get it to work ok in chrome? or at least both to behave the same?

Answer (score -1):

I just tried your code and it works on chrome for me.

However, since your using tables anyway you could always go back to pre-CSS days:

```
<tr>
    <td>Description</td>
    <td>Descriptions here</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Description</td>
    <td>Descriptions here</td>
</tr>
<tr height="*">
    <td colspan="2"><button /></td>
</tr>
```